# Why is an .rlib not generated in the target/debug directory after a successful build with CLion?

Tags: rust

I am trying a build a library using the CLion IDE with Rust plugin installed. After a successful build, the library is not generated in the `target/debug` directory.

This is my project structure:

**src/lib.rs**

```rust
pub mod Math;
```

**src/Math.rs**

```
pub struct Arithmetic {
    x: i32,
    y: i32,
}

impl Arithmetic {
    pub fn new(&mut self, x: i32, y: i32) {
        self.x = x;
        self.y = y;
    }

    pub fn add() -> i32 {
        2 + 3
    }

    pub fn sub() -> i32 {
        2 - 3
    }

    pub fn mul() -> i32 {
        2 * 3
    }

    pub fn div() -> i32 {
        2 / 3
    }
}
```

**Cargo.toml**

```
[package]
name = "Test_Lib"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your project structure looks fine, and should be building as a Rust library.

But you shouldn't be concerned whether `.rlib` is built, because the file alone isn't useful for anything other than Cargo's private usage.

If you're trying to make a library usable outside of internal Rust/Cargo usage (such as `.dll`/`.lib` or `.so`/`.a`), then you will have to use [the C ABI](https://docs.rust-embedded.org/book/interoperability/rust-with-c.html) or [C++ ABI](https://lib.rs/crates/cxx) and set `crate-type` to `staticlib` or `cdylib`.

If you want to use this library in other Rust projects, then don't even look into the `target` directory. Rust libraries aren't manually built one-by-one. Cargo builds the whole dependency tree in one go. Publish your crate on crates.io, or a [git repository](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html#specifying-dependencies-from-git-repositories) or add it to another project via [path](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html#specifying-path-dependencies).